# How to forecast time series with negative trend in test set and big uncertainty? (uncertainty due to Covid and Ukraine crisis)

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, uncertainty

Recently I started to create a machine learning model for a European customer for around 800 product time series. The goal is to produce a monthly forecast for the 6 months ahead.

Since this customer is a grocery wholesaler, a lot of the products experience supply chain difficulties due to Covid restrictions and now there might be some large effects due to the Ukraine crisis.

From the picture attached, you can already spectate the downwards trend in the last 6 months, which is pretty exceptional in most cases.

I did a lot of feature engineering and ran a bunch of algorithms (XGboost, Random Forest, SVM, Prophet with XGboost errors, Prophet with regressor).

In most cases the models fail to predict the downwards trend, which is actually not a big surprise.

I am searching for a more conservative approach, to achieve better accuracy and deal with uncertainty. One of my crude attempts was to multiply the forecast results by 0.5, which resulted in an accuracy almost twice as good.

If anyone has some ideas how to handle grocery wholesale forecasting during this challenging times, I would be glad for some advice.

Here some example time series:
[image]

Comment: Predictive models 100% draw from stable data generating processes. What we see now is very exceptional, inflation, high energy and food prices, massive uncertainty etc. So I guess any predictive model will inevitably fail to deliver „good“ results. At best you could piece together things like competition in the market, consumer price sensitivity etc. However, I guess this will be challenging and not very reliable.

Comment: Thanks for your input! What you are saying pretty much converges with my view of the situation. I was thinking about integration some external features. One of the challenges with macroeconomic data is for example, that most of the time, they are not up to date and missing one or several months at the end. In order to showcase the model to my customer, maybe it would be wise to train the model by cutting off the last 6 months of data. When it comes to decreasing demand, I am thinking about an early warnings system and an additional configuration, to adapt all forecast upwards or downwards